# How do I get the value from a single LiveData Object

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am trying to get values from a LiveData object but I get nullpointer exceptions

Here is my MainActivity onCreate method where i am trying to get those values

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCountDown = findViewById(R.id.main_countdown);

    mButtonStartPause = findViewById(R.id.button_start_pause);
    mButtonReset = findViewById(R.id.button_reset);
    mNewWorkout = findViewById(R.id.new_workout);
    mWorkouts = findViewById(R.id.my_workouts);
    mWorkRestLabel = findViewById(R.id.work_rest_label);

    mMainActivityViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    defaultWorkout.observe(this, new Observer<Workout>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Workout workout) {
            defaultWorkout = mMainActivityViewModel.getSelectedWorkout(1);
        }
    });

    //set up the workout parameters
    mNumberOfSets = defaultWorkout.getValue().getNumOfSets();
    mWorkoutDuration = (int) (defaultWorkout.getValue().getWorkDuration())* 1000;
    mRestDuration = (int) (defaultWorkout.getValue().getRestDuration()) * 1000;
    }
```

here is MainActivityViewModel

```
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

public class MainActivityViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
WorkoutRepository mWorkoutRepository;

public MainActivityViewModel( Application application) {
    super(application);
    mWorkoutRepository = new WorkoutRepository(application);
}

public LiveData<Workout> getSelectedWorkout(int workout) {
    return mWorkoutRepository.getSelectedWorkout(workout);
}


}
```

this isn't for a recyclerView or list just for a single object

Comment: also add `MainActivityViewModel` code.

Comment: Where do you get `NullPointerException`? Do you mean in `onChanged`?

Comment: the null pointer is after onChanged  where  `mNumberOfSets = defaultWorkout.getValue().getNumOfSets();` is